# Site App Permissions for REST API - Cannot set App title

Tags: permissions, sharepoint-rest-api, app

I am fairly new to Sharepoint aside from using lists like a spreadsheet. I am trying to create a workflow that will create an item in a list on a different site. I am using this guide that shows how to use REST API to accomplish this: https://www.portiva.nl/nl/portiblog/2016/11/03/sharepoint-designer-call-http-web-service-to-create-item-in-other-site-collection

I can add the app permission from site1 to site2, but when I try to set the App Title to something other than "Workflow", it does not actually change it. So I just have an app permission that says simply "Workflow". I would like to rename the title of the app permission so I know which is which. Any ideas?

Image:

https://i.postimg.cc/NMWMvtms/Image-725.png